# Cloudera ODBC ThriftExtension connection error

Tags: hive, ssis, connection, odbc, cloudera

I receive the following error message after I have deployed a SSIS package to a windows server.

"
ERROR [28000] [Cloudera] [ThriftExtension] (9) Error occurred while authenticating via SASL. Error details: SASL(-1): generic failure: Failed to initialize security context: No credentials are available in the security package.
"

The connection is an ODBC connection with the Cloudera Hive driver. I'm using the Thrift Transport SASL option and it works locally on the computer when I test the connection. Any ideas, what is happening after deployment with the same preferences?

I have tried the Delegate Kerberos Credentials option without any success.